# Object property containing nothing as default in C#

Tags: c#

In a class I have a property:

```
public Move plannedMove;
```

By default I would like it to contain nothing, so that I can test if it is set in my code in some some way similar to

```
if(!plannedMove)
```

Or something like that. I also want to be able to unset it so that it is blank to being empty. How can I do this?

Just in case I'm going about this totally wrong I will explain my original problem: my Player object needs to be able to have an optional precalculated move. In a method GetMove it needs to either return the precalculated move, or calculate one. How can I do this?

EDIT: Yikes, forgot to mention Move is a struct.

Comment: `public Move plannedMove;` is not a property, it's a field.

Answer (score 1):

By default this instance wont be instantiated and will be null, therefore

```
if (plannedMove != null)
{
   // do something here
}
```

would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Move plannedMove = null;

...    

if (plannedMove == null)
  plannedMove = ... // calculate new one

return plannedMove;
```

Comment: default value of object values are null why you doing `public Move plannedMove = null;`?

Answer (score 1):

You test whether it's empty with:

```
if (plannedMove == null)
```

You set it to empty with:

```
plannedMove = null;
```

When you declare it with `public Move plannedMove;`, it's set to empty (`null`) by default.

Answer (score 0):

set it to null in your constructor, or whenever you want it to have nothing:

```
this.plannedMove = null
```

then you can check it like:

```
if (this.plannedMove != null) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Move` is a reference type. So your variable `plannedMove` is `null` by default.

```
if (plannedMove == null)
{
   // do something
}
```

If it's a value type, check [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)